How to model it. Please provide me with some ideas and techniques, as well as the tools needed
Due to some reasons, I have just started learning Blender for a short time, but I urgently need to model the following object. Could any expert provide some guidance on how to approach it? I have no idea how to do it.

Hello and welcome. Please use a title that matches the content of the post. It should read like a question, be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the problem so that anyone searching for similar issues is likely to find this. Remove anything superfluous, avoid using words like "this", "help with", "issue" or "question about", instead describe what "it" is. Remember, your title is the first thing visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on it. See What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"

First draw the shapes of your object (here quickly made):

Extrude:

Move the vertices, extrude, etc so that it fits the real reliefs (again, quickly made here):


thank you very much ,your are god like

is that used blenderbezierutils?

Hello, what is blenderbezierutils?

https://github.com/Shriinivas/blenderbezierutils   This is blenderbezierutils

I don't know this addon, in what way would you want to use it?

I used this plug-in to outline the base and surface of the appearance, then used the Loop tool to bridge it, and finally fine-tuned it. I also used your idea to make the effect. Thank you for your guidance. I am now in the learning stage and will practice more various methods.
